# What is covered in music GCSE?

Tags: theory, composition, sight-reading, exam

I'm picking my GCSE options next month and I am considering music. Does anyone know what is covered in it and also what makes up the final GCSE grade?

Comment: It depends on which board is administering the exam, but you can get a general idea from a [publication](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5a7dbfb2e5274a5eb14e6f3e/GCSE_subject_content_for_music.pdf) on uk.gov